# Making a 100 x 100 pixel square with text in it a hyperlink

Tags: html, css

The code below breaks the text "Click here for your free prize" into four rows, like this:

```
Click here 
for your 
free 
prize
```

That's fine, but I would like to have this text in a square 100 pixels x 100 pixels, with a 2 pixel border around it.  The code below puts a 2 pixel border both above and below each row of the link.

How could I make the hyperlink a big 100 X 100 pixel square with the text arranged the same?

```
  echo "<div class='arizona'>";

                echo "<a href='http://www.stackoverflow.com/folder/folder/file.php?submission=".urlencode($submission)."&submissionid=".$submissionid."'>Click here for your free prize</a>";

                echo "</div>";
```

The CSS:

```
    .arizona { 
                position: absolute;
                top: 790px;
                left: 650px;
                color: #004993;
                width:100px;
                font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
                font-size: 12px;
                font-weight: normal;
                height: 100px;
                padding-bottom: 2px;
                padding-left: 5px;
                padding-right: 5px;
                padding-top: 2px;

    }

    .arizona a{ 
                margin-left:0px;
                margin-top:15px;
                color: #004284;
                width:100px;
                background-color: #FFFFFF;
                border:2px solid #004284;
                font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
                font-size: 15px;
                font-weight: normal;
                height: 100px;
                padding-bottom: 2px;
                text-decoration:none;
                padding-left: 5px;
                padding-right: 5px;
                padding-top: 2px;

    }

    .arizona a:hover{ 
                margin-left:0px;
                margin-top:15px;
                width:100px;
                background-color: #CAE1FF;
                color: #004284;
                border:2px solid #004284;
                font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
                font-size: 15px;
                font-weight: normal;
                height: 100px;
                padding-bottom: 2px;
                text-decoration:none;
                padding-left: 5px;
                padding-right: 5px;
                padding-top: 2px;

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
.arizona a{ display:block; }
```

and drop the padding.